# How can I import other file in service worker file using workbox-webpack-plugin injectMode?

Tags: vue-cli, workbox

I am using `vue-cli` and `workbox-webpack-plugin` `injectMode`

```
new InjectManifest({
  swSrc: './src/sw.ts',
  swDest: 'sw.js',
}),
```

in sw.ts, I try to import other file

```
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching'
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing'
import { WorkboxPlugin, setCacheNameDetails, RouteHandler } from 'workbox-core'
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from 'workbox-cacheable-response'
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration'
import Strategies, { CacheFirst, StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies'

// import other file
import { CustomMessage, MessageType, MESSAGE_META, SWRouting } from './utils/registerSW'
```

but when building APP, it will fail,

```
error:  js/chunk-2d213953.a6b52dae.js from Terser
Unexpected token: punc (:) [js/chunk-2d213953.a6b52dae.js:3,12]
```

when I remove this import statment, building works well.

So, Could I import other files ? How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, what you're trying to do should work. The `InjectManifest` plugin will kick off a `webpack` child compilation for the your `swSrc` file, and will inherit whatever plugins and config you have set up for your main, parent compilation. It should be able to bundle ES modules into a final service worker.

It sounds like there's something specific in one of those `./utils/registerSW` imports that is causing Terser to be unable to parse the bundled code, though. I would recommend starting by just importing a very small, no-op function from `./utils/registerSW`, and confirm that that works. Then try importing each of those functions from `./utils/registerSW` one at a time until you find the one that's causing issues, and check the original source code to see what might be triggering it.

It's *possible* that the child compilation kicked off by `InjectManifest` is misconfigured, and perhaps that's due to a bug that needs to be fixed, but I would start with those debugging steps first.

Comment: thank you so much. like you said, I find the reason,  it's because I used `import('workbox-window')` in `./utils/registerSW`.
I don't know why, but async import cause the Terser build error.